# Metallic taste and excessive salivation before vomiting

Tags: pain, vomit, saliva, taste, diarrhea

Is it normal to salivate profusely and have a strong bloody metalic taste before vomiting? This is coupled with orange yellow liquid vomit that also seems to have clear mucus mixed in. This is after all the normal stomach contents from the previous meal have been vomited along with 500 mg extra strength acetometophen for abdominal pains. The rest is all background information and I'm asking only about the metalic taste and salivation.

Comment: I don't know about the metallic taste, but the salivation is a normal body reflex when about to vomit. It protects the teeth and gums from the digestive tract's acid.

Comment: @Variax It's been explained to me that the metalic taste may be a physical sensation of rapid salivation. Thank you for helping me understand why the salivation occurs and it seems to have helped prevent some worry.